# Ошибка доступа в классе С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

```
class Matrix
{
private:
   int** pa = nullptr;
   int rows = 0;
   int cols = 0;
public:

   Matrix() {}
   Matrix(int r, int c);
   friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Matrix& a);
   friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Matrix& a);
   Matrix operator+ (Matrix);
   Matrix operator- (Matrix);
   ~Matrix()
   {
       for (int z = 0; z < rows; z++)
       {
           delete[] pa[z];
       }

       delete[] pa;
   }
};
```

Проблема: Вылазит ошибка в деструкторе с проблемой доступа к (**pa) (Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x7BC6E44B (ucrtbased.dll) в 1(2).exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xDDDDDDCD.)
С чем это может быть связано???

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего, вы не написали конструктор копирования, так что срабатывает умолчательный - который просто копирует указатели.

В итоге, у вас получаются две матрицы, которые на самом деле используют одну память для хранения данных - при удалении, первая матрица освобождает память, а вторая матрица пытается освободить уже освобожденную память, что приводит к падению.